# How to prove if the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n^3-1} $ converges or diverges with comparison test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n^3-1} $

I think that comparison test would give the easiest solution but i'm not sure how to apply it. I know that i need to find larger sum to prove convergence or smaller to prove divergence, so

$\frac{1}{n} $ would give us larger sum (correct me if i am wrong), and we know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} $ diverges, therefore our series from beginning of question diverges, but wolfram alpha said that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n^3-1} $ by comparison test converges.

Where am i making mistake, and what is the best way to apply comparison test on $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n^3-1} $?

Comment: try $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^2+n+1}$.

Comment: If you have $0\le u_n\le v_n$, and $\sum v_n$ is not convergent, then you can't say anything about $\sum u_n$.

Comment: $\frac{n+1}{n^3-1}\sim\frac{1}{n^2}$, so $\sum u_n$ is convergent.

Comment: The comparison test says if you're "bigger" than a divergent, then you're divergent, and if you're "smaller" than a convergent, then you're convergent. Remember that for non-negative series, convergence and divergence are basically "size" concepts.

Comment: "what is the best way to apply comparison test" The best way, in four steps (caution, no cleverness inside, just straight, basic, automatic steps): $$\text{First step:}\ n+1\sim n$$ $$\text{Second step:}\ n^3-1\sim n^3$$ $$\text{Third step:}\ \frac{n+1}{n^3-1}\sim\frac{n}{n^3}=\frac1{n^2}$$ $$\text{Fourth step:}\ \sum\frac1{n^2}\ \text{converges, QED}$$

Comment: But isn't sum of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ smaller than sum of $\frac{n+1}{n^{3}-1}$?

Comment: @TarsNolan Yes, but a constant factor catches that. If you compare to $\frac{2}{n^2}$, you have $\frac{n+1}{n^3-1} < \frac{2}{n^2}$ for $n \geqslant 2$. If you pick any $c > 1$, you have $\frac{n+1}{n^3-1} < \frac{c}{n^2}$ for all large enough $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the given series with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n=\sum\dfrac{1}{n^2}$.

If $u_n=\dfrac{n+1}{n^3+1}$ and $v_n=\dfrac{1}{n^2}$

then $\dfrac{u_n}{v_n}=\dfrac{(n^2)( n+1)}{n^3+1}=\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{n}}{1+\dfrac{1}{n^3}}\to 1<\infty$ as $n\to \infty$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ converges so does $\sum u_n=\sum\dfrac{n+1}{n^3+1}$

Answer (score 1):

What about exploiting creative telescoping? For any $n\geq 2$ we have
$$ 0\leq \frac{n+1}{n^3-1} \leq \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ 0\leq \sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{n+1}{n^3-1}\leq \sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{n(n-1)} = 1-\frac{1}{N}<1.\tag{2}$$